# why is javascript line break not working?

Tags: javascript

I need to show the code just like i have shown through my code as you can see. I want to draw the picture in the code. but the line break is not working. the output is showing all the things in a line.

```js
console.log(document.write('  ******\n'))
console.log(document.write('   ****\n'))
console.log(document.write('    **\n'))
console.log(document.write('   ****\n'))
console.log(document.write('  ******\n'))
console.log(document.write(' ********\n'))
console.log(document.write('**********\n'))
```

Comment: don't you need semicolumn ; at the end of each line ?

Comment: @thiebo — No, they don't.

Comment: instead of using `\n` you might need to use `<br>`

Comment: you need to use console.log(document.write('**********<br>'))

Comment: This will do: `console.log(document.write('********** <br>'))`

Comment: Also consider that `document.write` returns `undefined`, so those `console.log`s are perfectly useless

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
console.log(document.write('  ******<br/>'))
console.log(document.write('   ****<br/>'))
console.log(document.write('    **<br/>'))
console.log(document.write('   ****<br/>'))
console.log(document.write('  ******<br/>'))
console.log(document.write(' ********<br/>'))
console.log(document.write('**********<br/>'))
```

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions; it makes it harder to remove them. This answer is essentially the same as the advice given in the answers to the duplicate.

Comment: okay..sure i will do it

Comment: my question is not duplicate Mister. yes the answer could have been found there but I was not understanding thus I asked my own particular problem related question. so you better stop unnecessarily making my questions duplicate.